# ABCPdf add document javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, abcpdf

Is it possible to add document JavaScripts to a generated PDF using ABCPdf?

Answer (score 4):

If you mean, Javascript that is being executed after the document has been loaded, then have a look at [this documentation page](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf8net/source/5-abcpdf/xhtmloptions/2-properties/geckosubset.htm).

```
doc.HtmlOptions.UseScript = true;
doc.HtmlOptions.GeckoSubset.OnLoadScript =
@"(function() {
   window.ABCpdf_go = false;

   // your javascript code here

   window.ABCpdf_go = true;
})();";
```

Comment: Been trying to render google charts with ABc.pdf for quite a while, and this made it work. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to. There are some settings in the c# which will help.

You need to set the

```
doc.HtmlOptions.UseScript = true;
```

this will enable javascript to run.

it's probably worth setting the timeout to give it more time to finish loading

```
doc.HtmlOptions.Timeout = 10000;
```

and i've always had better results with the gecko rendering engine

```
doc.HtmlOptions.Engine = EngineType.Gecko;
```