# abc.pdf render google charts

Tags: c#, google-visualization, abcpdf

i'm trying to export charts created with googles api to pdf, using abcpdf.

i've tried the solution from these questions

[answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465742/can-abcpdf-create-a-pdf-from-a-page-created-with-javascript)
[answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194325/letting-the-javascript-finish-before-rendering-pdf-in-abc-pdf)

but neither works, and i get nothing created from the javascript.

the page i'm trying to render as pdf is

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="boop.aspx.cs" Inherits="boop" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function drawChart() {
        // Create the data table.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 3],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 1],
          ['Zucchini', 1],
          ['Pepperoni', 2]
        ]);
        var options = {
            'title': 'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
            'width': 400,
            'height': 300
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body  >
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
</form>
<asp:Label Text="hej" runat="server" />
</body>
</html>
```

when i access the page in the browser the chart is rendered, confirming that the COMContentLoaded even triggers the function.

the code where i want to save the chart as a pdf

```
 Doc theDoc = new Doc();

    theDoc.HtmlOptions.Timeout = 10000;
    theDoc.HtmlOptions.UseScript = true;
    theDoc.AddImageUrl("http://localhost:57833/boop.aspx");
    theDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("img/htmlimport.pdf"));

    theDoc.Clear();
```

my current code is a bit of a mixup from my previous effords using the beforementioned answers, without success. all i get in the pdf is my static label text.

i'm using abc.pdf8.

alternatively, doesanyone know of another free/cheap chart tool, for asp.net which abcpdf would be able to render as a pdf, or a tool that can render google charts as pdf ?

### **Fixed**

this short answer made it work.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13482231/744610

calling my drawchart function made the chart render and the pdf not contains everything needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this short answer made it work.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13482231/744610

calling my drawchart function made the chart render and the pdf not contains everything needed.

Comment: Hello. I have to draw charts and translate the view to pdf and actually I tried your sample but with no success. One thing that is different, I use MSHtml engine, not Gecko. Will be glad for any reply.

Comment: @SolomiiaKalinchuk If the answers i've linked to doesn't work for you, I'd suggest creating a seperate question explaining how you're trying to do it, with some code samples.